# Moving to Unicode - Questions about how it works

Tags: sql-server, unicode, ssis

I've been tasked with getting us ready for to go to Unicode for various character sets including Chinese, Russian, and Korean.
One of the things that I'm focusing on is SSIS. I've tested a simple lookup, and it works fine. But now I'm running into questions about these languages.

- Can you do an Upper on Kanji?
- How does sort work if you have Russian and Japanese in column?
- Hebrew and Arabic are both written Right to Left, however when I do a substring for the first character in Arabic I get the leftmost one, but Hebrew gives me the rightmost one.
- What about character sets? If I use a french keyboard and write a name, but another time use the same letters on a russian keyboard, will a Lookup find the connection?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: This is about 5 or 6 questions all rolled into one. You may find that you have better results keeping a question to a single question instead of a splattering of many, albeit related, questions.

Comment: Internationalization is HARD, and this is actually not a topic specific to SQL Server. You need to have some good requirements for what is expected, ESPECIALLY if you plan to have mixed languages in the same column.